# Quick Order module for Magento 2

Tags: magento

I want to create a module of quickorder in magento 2. I have got an issues with the code path block, ajax etc. Please someone can help me on this. How can i generate the JS/Ajax autosearch file for work like search product by product name or SKU then i add that product to shopping cart page. I try to help one module like "MageWorx_SearchSuitAutoComplete" but it product an issues. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make A controller with front name like Quickorder/index/index,now execute a function on Quickorder.

```
<?php 
namespace CompanyName\CustomApi\Controller\Index;

  class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
  {

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $httpClientFactory;
    protected $productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(    
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory

    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_httpClientFactory = $httpClientFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }   

    public function execute(){
        $search_text = $this->getRequest()->getPost('search_text');
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'))->addAttributeToFilter('name',
        array('like' => $search_text.' %'),
        array('like' => '% '.$search_text.' %'), 
        array('like' => '% '.$search_text) 
        ));
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($collection->getData());
       die();
    }
```

On input type make a jquery function and request a ajax call with keyup.

```
$('#quick-search').keyup(function(){
        var search_text = jQuery("#quick-search").val();
        try {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url : '<?php echo $block->getUrl('quickorder/index/index') ?>',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data: { 'search_text' :  search_text  },
                    type : 'post',
                    success : function(data) {
                        jQuery('.main-search-results').html(data.products);
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
            }
    });
```

Or you can also used require js instead of this jquery.

Thanks